# How to pass a variablename to unix command in subprocess in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to use unix diff command in subprocess , when I hardcode, it works fine, But I added it in a function where I need to pass these arguments to diff. How do I do it ?
In the below code, I have hardcoded , but I want infile to take file1.txt and outputfile as file2.txt.

```
def file_comparison_2(infile,outputfile):
    p = subprocess.Popen("diff file1.txt file2.txt",stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    (output, err) = p.communicate()
    FO = open("/users/home101/prabhus/python/pyunit-1.4.1/diff.txt", "wb")
    print("Command output : ", output)
    FO.write(output)
    FO.close()
```

Comment: subprocess.check_output() takes a list of arguments and handles various shell quirks for you, such as filenames with spaces.
 https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
p = subprocess.Popen("diff "+infile+" "+outfile,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
```

You can simply do this.

Comment: changing to p = subprocess.Popen("diff "+infile+" "+outputfile+" ",stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True) worked. Thanks

Comment: @Suma do use `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` if you want capture failure in command